# How to replace arbritary combinations of (special) characters and numbers using sed and regular expressions

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed

I have a csv file with nearly arbritary filled colums like this:

```
"bla","","blabla","bla::bla::blabla",19.05.16 12:00:03,123456789,"bla::38594f-47849-h945f",""
```

and now I want to replace the comma between the two numbers with a point:

```
"bla","","blabla","bla::bla::blabla",19.05.16 12:00:03.123456789,"bla::38594f-47849-h945f",""
```

I tried a lot but nothing helped. :-(

```
sed s/[0-9],[0-9]/./g data.csv
```

works but it delets the two numbers before and after the comma. So I tried things like

```
sed s/\(\.[0-9]\),\([0-9]\.\)/\1.\2/g data.csv
```

but that changed nothing.

Comment: Try `s/([0-9]),([0-9])/\1\.\2/g`

Comment: @lbarros `sed s/([0-9]),([0-9])/\1\.\2/g data.csv` didn't work: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token (`

Comment: It works if you put it between single quotes and if you use the `-E` switch before to use Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax. Remove the useless backslash before the dot.

Comment: @Sally do what Casimir said

Comment: `sed -E 's/([0-9]),([0-9])/\1\.\2/g' test.csv `

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks a lot, now it works :-)

Comment: @Sally: Note that AKS answer is also correct without the use of ERE. Other thing, if you already knows there is only one comma you want to replace per line, you don't need the g flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `s/\([0-9]\),\([0-9]\)/\1.\2/g`:

```
$ echo '"bla","","blabla","bla::bla::blabla",19.05.16 12:00:03,123456789,"bla::38594f-47849-h945f",""' | sed 's/\([0-9]\),\([0-9]\)/\1.\2/g'
"bla","","blabla","bla::bla::blabla",19.05.16 12:00:03.123456789,"bla::38594f-47849-h945f",""
```

[Regex Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/xV6rZ6/1)

You don't really need the additional dot `\.` in the capturing groups.